# preventDefault não funciona em Navegadores para Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Em navegadores para computador consigo prevenir a ação padrão da âncora normalmente, porém ao usar na maioria dos navegadores para celular não funciona.

Preciso que ao clicar no link o navegador não direcione para a URL do link, apenas mostre num alert qual é a URL que está no atributo **`href`**, segue código que estou utilizando:

```js
$(".myGallery a").on("click touchstart", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myGallery">
  <a href="https://www.yourhtmlsource.com/images/media/banjotooiebig.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.yourhtmlsource.com/images/media/banjotooiesmall.jpg" alt="Image">
  </a>
</div>
```

Tentei nos seguintes navegadores para **Android**:

- Chrome 70.0.3538.110
- Chrome 34.0.1847.114
- Opera Mini 35.0.2254.127755
- CM Browser 5.22.17.0003

Comment: Coloque um `return false;` no final da função.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar um `return false;` no fim da função do evento que a ação do elemento que disparou o evento não prosseguirá.

Em circunstâncias normais o `preventDefault()` deveria funcionar, conforme testei aqui no Chrome abaixo mencionado na pergunta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
$(".myGallery a").on("click touchstart", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).attr("href"));
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Funcionou nessa versão @Sam, será que tem uma forma de fazer funcionar nas outras?

Comment: Cara, estranho isso, nunca vi isso não funcionar rs... Pior que não tenho nem como testar porque não tenho como instalar versões anteriores desses navegadores. O Opera Mini, por exemplo, já está na versão 37 e não houve problemas.

Comment: Entendo, eu tenho um celular que não atualizo justamente para testar algumas funcionalidades, até o momento esse foi o único problema que não consegui resolver com navegadores antigos. Como não tenho como garantir com qual navegador o usuário vai acessar a aplicação tenho que me precaver.

Comment: Será que não é incompatibilidade com o jQuery? Tente fazer com JS puro.

Comment: Vou tentar agora com JS puro.

Comment: Com JS puro não foi...

Comment: Não sei se vai funcionar, mas para fins de teste, tente colocar `onclick="event.preventDefault()"` direto na tag <a>